# Excel 2013 OLAP Pivot (Grand Total)

Tags: excel-2013, olap-cube

I have a pivot table which is driven by SSAS.

The table shows a "Grand Total" and this is something I want to use in a pivot chart, but when creating a chart, it does not allow that column to be utilised.

I can't add a calculated field as the pivot is driven by olap, so I am running out of ideas.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your OLAP pivot table to cube functions and make a normal chart from the data rather than a pivot chart. Here's a link to get you started https://dataonwheels.wordpress.com/2015/01/27/excel-bi-tip-18-using-cube-functions-to-break-out-of-pivot-tables/